# How to create an available button in an One2many tree in a wizard?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I need to create a group of *Transient Models* to allow users to configure several settings through easy wizards.

In the main wizard, I need to show a *One2many* field (tree editable inline), which points to other *Transient Model*. The user will be able to add some lines to the *One2many* field, and each one of these lines will have a button. If the user clicks on this button, it will open another wizard.

The problem is that the button of each line is always readonly, since Odoo does not allow to click on a button whose record is still not stored in the database.

With non-transient models, to click on the button inside a line of the tree view of an *One2many* field, you must click on the *Save* button of the parent form before, to store the main record and each one of the lines. This is very uncomfortable for users indeed.

But perform that action in a *Transient Model* is a non-sense, mainly because it does not have a *Save* button, but your own buttons.

Any ideas of how to do in this situation?

Comment: You can trick the user instead of adding save button, name it next,  the record will be saved and the buttons of lines appears and they can click on them, so mentally they don't know they saved the record in database when they clicked Next button,  what do you think about this idea. Like installation wizard

Comment: I've tried several ways, but finally, what you suggested me is what I did.Thank you for the idea @CharifDZ.